# Do we want to be able to opt-out of the new duplicate hammer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

StackExchange is testing out a new feature that allows [owners of gold badges in specific tags to instantly close questions in those tags as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/203444). I know that [we've had issues with people being too quick to close questions](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/738/music-se-suffers-from-trigger-happy-closers), so if SE rolls out the new feature network-wide, would we want to be able to turn it off if it makes our issues with close votes worse?

I've already asked a question on Meta.SE [requesting that child sites be able to opt out of the feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231513/please-allow-sites-to-opt-out-of-the-duphammer), citing our situation.

Comment: We don't have anyone who is close to having a gold badge in a specific tag. In fact we only have one person who has a silver badge in a specific tag and that's 
Dr Mayhem and he is 430 up votes away from a gold in the guitar tag so I don't think it's anything to worry about.

Comment: @Dom -- do you want to post that as an answer? I was going to say the same thing.

Comment: Agreed. By the time we have some folds with gold badges we should be a much more mature site

Comment: I disagree that this SE is trigger-happy about closing, so I don’t see this as a problem at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even if we did have gold-tag-badge holders (which we don't), **this would only apply to duplicates**. Closing as a duplicate is a unique form of closing. A duplicate essentially means, "Your question has already been asked and answered here". This is quite different from closing for other reasons. The other reasons for closing sum up to " this question is not a good fit for this site. plz improve".

Our gold-tag-badge holders would have a good amount of insight into what is and isn't a duplicate. I don't believe this would be abused or that it would further or trigger-happy closing problem.